# Jersey - populate java beans from XML string

Tags: java, json, jaxb, jersey, jax-rs

I have a Jersey client that is successfully calling a REST service and populating the associated Java Beans `CustomerType` based on this code:

```
WebResource service = client.resource(SECURE_BASE_URL);.
CustomerType cust = service.path("customer").path("23210")
    .accept(MediaType.TEXT_XML).get(CustomerType.class);
```

What I would like is to call the service with

```
 service.path("customer").path("23210").accept(MediaType.TEXT_XML).get(String.class);
```

to get the XML string and then convert the XML to the `CustomerType` bean.  I would like to do it this way for logging and to help with designing the system.  Is there a ways to convert the XML to the bean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many ways to do that. If your `CustomerType` class is JAXB-annotated (`@XmlRootElement` or whatever), you can simply use an `Unmarshaller` constructed via a `JAXBContext` (that you have previously initialized with your packages) like this:

```
CustomerType customerType = (CustomerType) jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller()
        .unmarshal( new StringReader(yourString) );
```

Comment: Quite right, I had actually found that method of doing it.  I was hoping for a native Jersey way to do it but I suppose it doesn't matter enough to worry about it.

Answer (score 0):

Jersey provides a logging filter. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2332515/how-to-get-jersey-logs-at-server) answers your question.

Comment: Indeed, and if you look at my question, I mentioned that I was able to go directly to the `CustomerType` object.  I was looking for a slick way to convert the returned XML to the `CustomerType` by going through Jersey but without making a second call to the server.