# Jersey: Print the actual request

Tags: java, jersey

How can I view the actual request that Jersey generates and sends to the server?  I am having issues with a particular request and the fellow running the webserver asked to see the full request (with headers and the such).

Comment: for logging at the server side see the following post:

[How to get jersey logs at server?][1]


  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2332515/how-to-get-jersey-logs-at-server

Answer (score 105, accepted):

If you're just using Jersey Client API, [LoggingFilter](https://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/1.9/jersey/com/sun/jersey/api/client/filter/LoggingFilter.html) (client filter) should help you:

```
Client client = Client.create();
client.addFilter(new LoggingFilter(System.out));
WebResource webResource = client.resource("http://localhost:9998/");
ClientResponse response = webResource.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                                         .get(ClientResponse.class);
```

Otherwise, you can again log both request and response on server using other [LoggingFilter](https://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/1.9/jersey/com/sun/jersey/api/container/filter/LoggingFilter.html) (container filter).

Comment: This `addFilter` method doesn't exist in Jersey 2.x.  How do you use this now?

Comment: JAX-RS 2.x provides functionality that is equivalent to the Jersey 1.x proprietary client API. More details:  https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/user-guide.html#mig-client-api

Comment: For people interested in customizing the log output, they can create  their own LoggingFilter http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30187514/how-to-log-request-body-in-jax-rs-client

Answer (score 66):

Since **Jersey 2.23**, there's a [`LoggingFeature`](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/apidocs/latest31x/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/logging/LoggingFeature.html) you could use. The following is a bit simplified example, please note that you can register the feature on [`WebTarget`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/client/WebTarget.html) as well.

```
Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName());

Feature feature = new LoggingFeature(logger, Level.INFO, null, null);

Client client = ClientBuilder.newBuilder()
        .register(feature)
        .build();

Response response = client.target("https://www.google.com")
        .queryParam("q", "Hello, World!")
        .request().get();
```

JavaDoc of `LoggingFeature` says that the request "and/or" the response is logged lol. On my machine, both are logged.

Comment: This works great for Jersey 2.25 but in 2.7 which I am using, the "logging" package is no longer located within org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-common. Do you know which package it was moved to in 2.7?

Comment: This does not print the body of the request or response. It only shows the headers

Comment: @DavidBrossard Use org.glassfish.jersey.logging.LoggingFeature.Verbosity.PAYLOAD_ANY as a constructor parameter to control this.

Answer (score 54):

@ivan.cikic's answer is for Jersey 1.x.  Here's how you do it in Jersey 2.x:

```
import org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientConfig;
import org.glassfish.jersey.filter.LoggingFilter;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import javax.ws.rs.client.Client;
import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder;
import javax.ws.rs.client.Entity;
import javax.ws.rs.client.WebTarget;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Form;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

...

        ClientConfig config = new ClientConfig();

        Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient(config);
        client.register(new LoggingFilter());
```

This is irrelevant but I just *have* to complain: The new `LoggingFilter` is really annoying because it forces you to use Java Util Logging.  It would be better if it gave me control over the logger.  Seems like a step backwards in design.

Comment: I know this is an old answer, but I have a question - do you know how to get the logger to print ALL of the information contained in a request? In particular, cookies. I've used the `LoggingFilter(Logger logger, boolean PrintEntity)` constructor, but even that doesn't print cookies.

Comment: LoggingFilter is now deprecated. You should use Martin's answer of the LoggingFeature. This also supports the Verbosity enum to print out a varying amount of detail. It should print out headers, which should include cookies.

Comment: For some reason `LoggingFeature` doesn't print anything and `LoggingFilter` does print... ‍♂️

Answer (score 4):

All these answers are pretty close but they lack the setting to log the request and response body. At least with Jersey 2.30.1 this is how I accomplish logging the request and response including their respective bodies:

```
import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder;
import org.glassfish.jersey.logging.LoggingFeature;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("LoggingFeature");
logger.setLevel(Level.ALL);
ClientBuilder.newClient()
  .target("https://www.example.com")
  .register(new LoggingFeature(
    logger,
    Level.ALL,
    LoggingFeature.Verbosity.PAYLOAD_ANY,
    8192))
  .request()
  .get();
```

Technically the `Level.All` and `8192` values could be `null`. I just provide them here to be concise.

Answer (score 0):

For version 3.1.X it must be:

```
Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("test");
LoggingFeature loggingFeature = new LoggingFeature(logger, Level.INFO, Verbosity.PAYLOAD_ANY,null);
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
client.register(loggingFeature);
```

`Level.ALL` is NOT Working