# jersey.api.client.WebResource - how to debug/log the request headers

Tags: http-headers, jersey

I am using jersey to generate http requests and I would like to be able to see the **request** before it is sent (for debugging purposes).

For example:

```
WebResource resource = client.resource(url);
resource.header("aa", "bb");
resource.getHeaders(); // Error: how can I do it?
```

thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jersey: Print the actual request](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6860661/jersey-print-the-actual-request)

Answer (score 9):

You can use [LoggingFilter](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/1.8/jersey/com/sun/jersey/api/client/filter/LoggingFilter.html), as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6860661/jersey-print-the-actual-request/6873911#6873911)

Answer (score -2):

You need to add init-params and then implement `ContainerRequestFilter`

Put it in your `web.xml` Please note that `com.az.jersey.server.AuthFilter` is your class that has implemented mentioned above interface.

```
<init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequestFilters</param-name>
            <param-value>com.sun.jersey.api.container.filter.LoggingFilter;com.az.jersey.server.AuthFilter</param-value>
        </init-param>



public class AuthFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {
    /**
     * Apply the filter : check input request, validate or not with user auth
     * 
     * @param containerRequest
     *            The request from Tomcat server
     */
    @Override
    public ContainerRequest filter(ContainerRequest containerRequest) throws WebApplicationException {
        //GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, ...
        String method = containerRequest.getMethod();
        // myresource/get/56bCA for example
        String path = containerRequest.getPath(true);         

        return containerRequest;
    }
```