# How to debug Jersey 2.x Client Api

Tags: java, client, jersey-2.0

I need to see the content of Jerset 2.x Client API post requests before it is sent. 
I found this:

[jersey.api.client.WebResource - how to debug/log the request headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7149548/jersey-api-client-webresource-how-to-debug-log-the-request-headers)

But its related to Jersey 1.x

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out Daniel Kaplan's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6860661/jersey-print-the-actual-request/6873911#6873911).
Please note - I followed the link from your question and went through the complete post which linked to the answer.