# How do I get useful logging when using the Jersey client?

Tags: java, logging, jersey, jersey-client

I am using the Jersey client to communicate with a remote server.  I do not have access to this server's logs.  Therefore, it's essential that I see what I'm sending over from the client in order to troubleshoot my code.  How can I increase logging to see at least:

1. The url I'm sending a request to
2. The parameter values
3. Headers
4. The request body (assuming I'm posting)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jersey: Print the actual request](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6860661/jersey-print-the-actual-request)

Answer (score 2):

have you tried looking at [LoggingFilter](https://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/1.9/jersey/com/sun/jersey/api/client/filter/LoggingFilter.html)

Comment: Do you have any sample code that shows how to use this?

Comment: have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2332515/how-to-get-jersey-logs-at-server and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6860661/jersey-print-the-actual-request/6873911#6873911

Comment: That second link is pretty much of a duplicate of my question.  I'm going to vote to close this.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Actually, now that I've tried that, I notice that `addFilter` doesn't exist on the `Client` in jersey 2.x.

Comment: do you use ClientBuilder to create your client? it has a method register which you can use it to register your LoggingFilter like this:
`Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient().register(LoggingFilter.class);`
Not tested though