# How to log request body in JAX-RS client

Tags: logging, jax-rs, servlet-filters

I need to see my request body with a client JAX-RS request in order to verify that the serialization works correct and reuse the request for test clients like [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/).

I know it's possible to activate logging with Jersey using for example `resource.addFilter(new com.sun.jersey.api.client.filter.LoggingFilter());`. However, I don't use Jersey or RESTEasy implementation directly, but abstracted via JAX-RS API:

```
final WebTarget target = 
        ClientBuilder.newBuilder().build().target("http://localhost:8080");
```

How can I enable logging here?

---

## Result

[The answer from @peeskillet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30195076/2854723) + [this snippet](http://1987.io/questions/3342335/get-request-body-of-my-request).

However sometimes the `close()` method from the snippet is not being invoked by the JAX-RS implementation (`org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-client-3.0.11.FINAL` in this case).

Comment: You could just homegrow one based on `LoggingFilter` source code?

Comment: But where or how can I register it then?

Comment: With `@WebFilter` or `<filter>`.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

JAX-RS 2.0 (which it looks like you're using), has the [`ClientRequestFilter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/client/ClientRequestFilter.html). You can register it with the `Client` or even the `WebTarget`. From the `filter` method, you can get the entity, and do your logging

```
public class LoggingFilter implements ClientRequestFilter {
    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(LoggingFilter.class.getName());

    @Override
    public void filter(ClientRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {
        LOG.log(Level.INFO, requestContext.getEntity().toString());
    }
}

[...]

Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
client.register(new LoggingFilter());
```

---

Also the [`ClientRequestContext` API](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/client/ClientRequestContext.html) for some other goodies you might find interesting.

#### UPDATE

**See Also:**

- [JAX-RS 2 print JSON request](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36676017/2587435), for a complete/better implementation.

Comment: That works basically, however the the method `requestContext.getEntity()` returns the Entity as object before the serialization happens. Is there a way to get the plain text body that will be sent?

Comment: The background is that I try to utilize both  the library `jackson-datatype-joda` and a custom Jackson-MixIn. I want to see the serialized output to prove the serialization called by JAX-RS works right.

Comment: You might need to marshal the object yourself inside the filter. Only easy way I can think of. Kinda doubles the workload though. There might be other ways, but it's not really something I have explored.

Comment: I've found [this solution](http://1987.io/questions/3342335/get-request-body-of-my-request) which works basically although not looking too elegant

Comment: The site is no longer available... could you share what you found?

Comment: @thomas.mc.work it's also not available on archive.org

Comment: Sorry, I can't rmemeber what I've found there anymore. My fault to post only the link instead of the core content.