# How to read from a CommittingOutputstream?

Tags: java, jersey, outputstream

I am writing a Logging Interceptor to log response body for a Jersey Http Client. I have access to an object of type
https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/master/core-common/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/message/internal/CommittingOutputStream.java

But I don't see any `toByteArray()` kind of method to read the stream like in a ByteArrayOutputStream.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36677808/2587435

Comment: my fault, this library has declared the CommitingOutputStream as final, hence impossible to extend. I can't think a reason to do so, while com.sun.jersey.api.client did declare the class as abstract, with an overrideable protected getOutputStream method. I just don't get the point of this. : S