# Log the request body of JSON @ Jersey Rest WS

Tags: java, eclipse, jersey

How do I print/Log the request body of JSON from below code @ Rest WS with Jersey in Java. I can log the response for this. I am struggling to log/print the exact request body.

Thanks in advance.

WebTarget target = client.target(url);

```
    //authentication strings
    String authString = "username:password";
    byte[] authEncBytes = Base64.encodeBase64(authString.getBytes());
    String authStringEnc = new String(authEncBytes);

    Response res = target.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)   
            .header("content-type", "application/json")
            .header("Authorization", "Basic " + authStringEnc)
            .header("accept", "application/json,text/plain")    
            .header("X-senderTimestamp", new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()))
            .header("X-appCode", "IVR")
            .header("X-sessionId", XsessionId)
            .post(Entity.entity(getAccountInfoInputBean, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
```

Comment: May be a duplication of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6860661/jersey-print-the-actual-request

Comment: Which JAX-RS version are you using?

Answer (score 3):

### Jersey 2.23 and later

In Jersey 2.23 and later, the [`LoggingFeature`](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.23/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/logging/LoggingFeature.html) will do the trick for you. It must be registered as following:

```java
ClientConfig clientConfig = new ClientConfig();
clientConfig.property(LoggingFeature.LOGGING_FEATURE_VERBOSITY_CLIENT, 
                      LoggingFeature.Verbosity.PAYLOAD_ANY);
Client client = ClientBuilder.newBuilder(clientConfig);
```

With the default verbosity settings ([`LoggingFeature.Verbosity.PAYLOAD_TEXT`](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.23.2/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/logging/LoggingFeature.Verbosity.html#PAYLOAD_TEXT)), the request and response headers will be logged, as well as the entity if considered a *readable text*. The entity is considered a readable text, if the media type is `text/*` or is one of:

- `application/atom+xml`
- `application/json`
- `application/svg+xml`
- `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`
- `application/xhtml+xml`
- `application/xml`

Note that the entity is logged up to the specified maximum number of bytes (see [`LoggingFeature.LOGGING_FEATURE_MAX_ENTITY_SIZE`](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.23.2/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/logging/LoggingFeature.html#LOGGING_FEATURE_MAX_ENTITY_SIZE)).

Have a look at the [Jersey documentation about logging](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/logging_chapter.html) for more details.

### Older versions

In older versions, use [`LoggingFilter`](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.22/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/filter/LoggingFilter.html). According to the documentation, as of Jersey 2.23 and later, this filter has been deprecated and will be removed soon.

Answer (score 0):

You can use LoggingFilter to log to System.out.

```
client.addFilter(new LoggingFilter(System.out));
WebTarget target = client.target(url);
```