# How can I log the raw rest request/response as seen by Jersey?

Tags: jersey

I have a Jersey-based REST service deployed on apache tomcat.  I would like to log the raw requests / responses made to the survey.  The data that I am looking for is the URL and the body (in the case of POST/PUT messages).

How can I enable this logging?

Comment: this may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2332515/how-to-get-jersey-logs-at-server