# Jersey Server Logging /w Logback

Tags: java, tomcat, logging, jersey, logback

How would I go about getting Jersey LoggingFilter working with logback? I saw this post:

[How to get jersey logs at server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2332515/how-to-get-jersey-logs-at-server)

but it unfortunately relies on the `java.util.Logger`. I am not super well versed when it comes to web.xml configuration so I would not know how to go about offering the `init-param` different loggers.

Note that I am using Spring 3 for dependency injection, but am creating loggers per class with the code:

`Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyClass.class);`

Hope this is enough information. If not, let me know.

My web container is Tomcat 7.0.12.

Answer (score 4):

I tried to use Jersey-Spring4 with logback and was not able to redirect access logs via the `LoggingFeature` to my logback-logger.
The logback-logger was configured like `<logger name="org.glassfish.jersey" level="INFO"/>` and I assumed this should do the trick.

After I learned that Jersey is using JUL, I was sad for a few minutes and carried on with using `org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j`.
To make it work I had to

```
private void registerLogback(final ServletContext servletContext) {
    servletContext.addListener(new LogbackConfigListener());

    //this is only necessary if you externalise logback.xml from resources     
    try { LogbackConfigurer.initLogging(servletContext.getRealPath("/WEB-INF/logback.xml")); }
    catch (FileNotFoundException | JoranException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }

    LogManager.getLogManager().reset();
    SLF4JBridgeHandler.removeHandlersForRootLogger();
    SLF4JBridgeHandler.install();
}
```

in my `WebApplicationInitializer.onStartup(ServletContext servletContext)`.

My `ResourceConfig` looked like

```
register(new LoggingFeature(createLogger(), Level.ALL, LoggingFeature.DEFAULT_VERBOSITY, 0)); 

private Logger createLogger() {
    final ConsoleHandler consoleHandler = new ConsoleHandler();
    consoleHandler.setLevel(Level.ALL);

    final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Logger.GLOBAL_LOGGER_NAME);
    logger.setLevel(Level.ALL);
    logger.addHandler(consoleHandler);

    return logger;
}
```

What logged access to the console. Removing the `ConsoleHandler` sadly did not end up in logs being logged to the logback-logger, the just got swallowed. **But** the *red* log statements on the console gave me the hint that this could be `STDERR`, albeit their were `INFO`.

Finally [LoggingFeature not logging correctly based on configuration on constructor](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/issues/3527) gave me the missing piece.

My final and working `ResourceConfig` ended up as

```
register(new LoggingFeature(Logger.getLogger(LoggingFeature.DEFAULT_LOGGER_NAME), Level.INFO, LoggingFeature.DEFAULT_VERBOSITY, 0));
```

Where `LoggingFeature.DEFAULT_LOGGER_NAME` and `Level.INFO` seem to be the crucial part.

In the end I don't know exactly went wrong, but this is the result of my guessing and it works. If this helps anybody I am happy.

Answer (score 2):

You can bridge `java.util.Logger` calls to Logback by using the [jul-to-slf4j](http://www.slf4j.org/legacy.html#jul-to-slf4j) bridge.
With that installed you can control Jersey logging (and any other JUL) with your logback.xml.

Comment: So I just add `handlers = org.slf4j.bridge.SLF4JBridgeHandler` to a `logging.properties` file in my classpath?

Comment: Yes. Or programmatically bu calling SLF4JBridgeHandler.install() upon initialization

Comment: So the documentation says "Once SLF4JBridgeHandler is installed, logging by j.u.l. loggers will be directed to SLF4J". What does this mean exactly? I am using logback with SLF4J and I have my logging redirected to several files. Am I going to need different configuration options to catch this? I guess I am asking what SLF4J is going to do with this information?

Answer (score 1):

**`Slf4jLogger`** from `org.apache.cxf:cxf-core` package is another option. It implements `java.util.logging.Logger` and delegate cals to slf4J.

Jersey server:

```
ResourceConfig config = new ResourceConfig(HelloWorldResource.class);
config.register(
    new Slf4jLogger(this.getClass().getName(), null));
```

Jersey client:

```
ClientBuilder
    .newClient()
    .register(
        new LoggingFeature(
                new Slf4jLogger(this.getClass().getName(), null)));
```