# LoggingFilter is ignored in Jersey and embedded Jetty

Tags: java, jersey, embedded-jetty

I'm trying to configure `LoggingFilter` for Jersey in an embedded Jetty setup. The glue code that is used is as follows:

```
ServletContainer servletContainer = new ServletContainer(application);
ServletHolder servletHolder = new ServletHolder(servletContainer);
servletHolder.setInitParameter("com.sun.jersey.config.feature.Debug", "true");
servletHolder.setInitParameter("com.sun.jersey.config.feature.Trace", "true");
servletHolder.setInitParameter("com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequestFilters", 
  "com.sun.jersey.api.container.filter.LoggingFilter");
servletHolder.setInitParameter("com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponseFilters", 
  "com.sun.jersey.api.container.filter.LoggingFilter");
```

But the logging filter is actually ignored and I see no relevant logs in the console. How can I do this? Tested both on Jersey 1.x and 2.x.

A [relevant answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2362106/248082) describes how to achieve this using `web.xml`.

Comment: Your code looks to be equivalent to an XML servlet configuration except for one detail - the servlet name and class. Maybe you just didn't paste that portion here.

Have you tried that XML configuration solution and confirmed it actually works in your case?

Comment: Did you configure JDK logging appropriately?

Comment: @Cebence `ServletHolder` serves as `web.xml`. The application runs and it works.

Comment: @skirsch I see logs either from Jetty or Jersey and the application itself.

Comment: @nobeh Sorry, I thought the `ServletContainer` was Jetty code. Just seen a full example https://github.com/yamsellem/Backbone-Jersey/blob/master/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is a very subtle nuance of the documented behavior of `ServletContainer` if it isn't an outright bug. The [`ServletContainer` docs](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/latest/jersey/com/sun/jersey/spi/container/servlet/ServletContainer.html) on the subject of init params read as:

> All initialization parameters are added as properties of the created ResourceConfig.

The answer is hidden in there. Specifically, if the ResourceConfig instance isn't created by the ServletContainer, then the servlet init parameters aren't added as properties and thus won't influence your app's configuration. When you provide your own `Application` instance, as you did with the `new ServletContainer(application)`, initialization follows roughly this course:

Your code invokes the following `ServletContainer` constructor with your `Application` instance:

```
public ServletContainer(Application app) {
    this.app = app;
}
```

The container initializes your `ServletContainer` as part of a typical `Servlet` lifecycle:

```
protected void init(WebConfig webConfig) throws ServletException {
    webComponent = (app == null)
            ? new InternalWebComponent()
            : new InternalWebComponent(app);
    webComponent.init(webConfig);
}
```

There goes your `Application` instance into the `InternalWebComponent` constructor. An `InternalWebComponent` is just a slight customization of `WebComponent`, so:

```
InternalWebComponent(Application app) {
    super(app);
}
```

calls:

```
public WebComponent(Application app) {
    if (app == null)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();

    if (app instanceof ResourceConfig) {
        resourceConfig = (ResourceConfig) app;
    } else {
        resourceConfig = new ApplicationAdapter(app);
    }
}
```

This is where, since you provided an `Application` instance directly, a `ResourceConfig` is built for you in one of the branches of that second `if`. Immediately after construction, `WebComponent.init()` is called on the new component (refer back to the `ServletContainer.init()` call above, where we came from). Inside this `init()` call is where the "created ResourceConfig" referred to by the docs *would be* created, but in your case, one already exists, as shown by the trail we followed to get here. I.e., the `resourceConfig` isn't null, so the important line below doesn't execute:

```
public void init(WebConfig webConfig) throws ServletException {
    ...
    if (resourceConfig == null)
        resourceConfig = createResourceConfig(config);
    ...
}
```

That `createResourceConfig()` method (still in `WebComponent`) reads as:

```
private ResourceConfig createResourceConfig(WebConfig webConfig)
        throws ServletException {
    final Map<String, Object> props = getInitParams(webConfig);
    final ResourceConfig rc = createResourceConfig(webConfig, props);
    rc.setPropertiesAndFeatures(props);
    return rc;
}
```

You can see in that call that `setPropertiesAndFeatures()` is used to copy the servlet's init params into the `ResourceConfig` instance. Unfortunately, this is the *only* place where that call is made, and in your case, execution never makes it here, basically because of your use of one of the non-default `ServletContainer` constructors.

I expect that the original authors wrote `ServletContainer` with just one, no-arg constructor and the other two were added later on for ease of use with Servlet 3.0 containers without realizing that this behavior was being introduced. Otherwise, I'd expect to see *some* mention of it in the docs.

So, long story short: either use the default `ServletContainer` constructor or find a way to take care of this part yourself:

```
Map<String, Object> props = getInitParams(webConfig);
rc.setPropertiesAndFeatures(props);
```

The first way is probably the simplest. For instance, you could specify your `Application` class as an init parameter, too, as long as there's nothing requiring you to instantiate it ahead of time, such as:

```
servletHolder.setInitParameter("javax.ws.rs.Application", "org.foo.MyApplication");
```

That way, the "normal" initialization path will be taken, meaning the `WebComponent` will create the `ResourceConfig` for you and apply the init params correctly.

Comment: This `ServletContainer > Servlet` behavior is basically inverson of control (IoC) just like Spring's Dependency Injection - if you want your beans autowired you must not create them yourself with `new`. Same applies to servlets.

Comment: @Cebence: I don't think I agree with that comparison. Take for example Spring's [DispatcherServlet](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/DispatcherServlet.html), which recently got a [new constructor](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/DispatcherServlet.html#DispatcherServlet(org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext)) that lets you provide an existing Spring context for use in a Servlet 3.0 environment. That works as you'd expect. This doesn't.

Comment: Yes, but I didn't say `3.0`. One would think after 4-5 years the implementation would be mature.

Comment: @RyanStewart Thanks for the time for this answer. Maybe, if you're interested, this works with Jersey 1.x but since in Jersey 2.x namespaces have changed, I have not yet found the configuration for the filters.

Comment: @nobeh: Sorry, but I've looked a little, and I can't find them either :\

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be doing it wrong.

```
// Creating an instance of Jersey servlet, right?
ServletContainer servletContainer = new ServletContainer(application);

// Putting it in a container by reference.
ServletHolder servletHolder = new ServletHolder(servletContainer);
```

[This page](https://cwiki.apache.org/WICKET/wicket-without-webxml-embedded-jetty.html) doesn't create the servlet like you do:

```
ServletHolder sh = new ServletHolder(WicketServlet.class);
```

This way Jetty creates an instance, and calls servlet's `init()`.
In your case you might need to call `init()` but I am not sure where will you get the `ServletConfiguration` instance.

**UPDATE:**
You should try it this way:

```
  ServletHolder servletHolder = new ServletHolder(ServletContainer.class);
  servletHolder.setInitParameter("javax.ws.rs.Application", "MyRESTApplication");
  servletHolder.setInitParameter("com.sun.jersey.config.feature.Debug", "true");
  servletHolder.setInitParameter("com.sun.jersey.config.feature.Trace", "true");
  servletHolder.setInitParameter("com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequestFilters",
      "com.sun.jersey.api.container.filter.LoggingFilter");
  servletHolder.setInitParameter("com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponseFilters",
      "com.sun.jersey.api.container.filter.LoggingFilter");

  ServletContextHandler contextHandler = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
  contextHandler.addServlet(servletHolder, "/services/*");
  server.setHandler(contextHandler);
```