# Ajax Post request to a Jax-rs service

Tags: java, javascript, html, jquery, jax-rs

I'm trying to do a simple post request from a browser and `415 Unsupported Media` is show in browser's console, in the console it says too that the `Type`is `text/html`, maybe I'm mising something stupid here but seriously I'm doing post request from an android client and everything is find with the server side, so i guess (since I'm not familiar with js) it's a javascript problem I'm having here, here are the portions of interest of the code:

ajax (this function is called `send` and it does some things before to create the json, that part it's ok and tested, the json is being genereated successfully):

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'webresources/serverConfig/save/',
        type: 'post',
        dataType:'json',
        data: jsonObj
    });
```

how i call the javascript in the HTML form:

```
<form action="javascript:send()"  method="post">
```

JAX-rs service:

```
@Path("serverConfig/")
public class ConfigurationSaverService {

@POST
    @Path("save/")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public void save(Configuration configuration){
    //config stuffs here.
}
```

`Edit:` due to @adrianplattner's answer, it's important to say that I'm using `glassfish 4.0`, so i didn't need to add jersey's dependencies, I also try `glashfish 3.1` and still get the same HTTP error.

`EDIT 2:` Header:

```
 headers: { 
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json' 
},
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add jersey dependency:

```
 <dependency>
     <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
     <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
     <version>1.11</version>
 </dependency>
```

that should resolve ur problem

Answer (score 0):

Default `Content-Type` of jQuery.ajax() call is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8` (see [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)) but you're expecting to consume `application/json` in your JAX-RS resource. Set the `contentType` parameter of your call to `application/json`.

Comment: i did this but it didn't work, I also try to set some parameters in header like theon's answer in here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11492325/post-json-fails-with-415-unsupported-media-type-spring-3-mvc but it didn´t solve the issue, do i need a Entity wrapper or something?

Comment: Can you try to turn on LoggingFilter (as described in `EDIT 1` in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/18033725/290799) and share the headers of the request with us?

Comment: edited with header now, and i don't know how to make my maven Jax-rs project to produce the web.xml and i don't really want to add it manually.

Comment: You don't need to create `web.xml`, there are 3 ways how to register the LoggingFilter (all of them are described in the link). I was curious about headers that come to the server and are logged into the server log (when LoggingFilter is enabled).

Comment: i added "@XmlRootElement" to Configuration class and it gave me a Bad Request error, without the XmlRoo...t Anotation i did a successful post request from an Android client.